# .htaccess redirect all subdomain request to current subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I got this :

```
-- root           # example.com 
   profile        # example.com/profile

----- subdomain1  # subdomain1.example.com
----- subdomain2  # subdomain2.example.com
----- subdomain3  # subdomain3.example.com
```

the problem is when request from subdomain1.example.com/profile or subdomain1.example.com/about they always redirect to example.com/profile

I wish to all request from subdomain, ex: subdomain1.example.com/profile or subdomain1.example.com/profile will redirect to that current request not redirected to root domain ex: example.com/profile

how to make it with .htaccess ?

Comment: Before anyone can answer this you have to give much more details about your setup. What is the _current_ setup? How does it work? how are those 'subdomains' configured?

Comment: I have not any .htaccess configuration

Comment: Well there are a few more things to a server configuration apart from some .htaccess file. As I asked before: how are those 'subdomains' configured?

Comment: one moment arkascha I will find out first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the DocumentRoot for your subdomain to the root of that subdomain. For example, /path/to/subdomain1.example.com should be the DocumentRoot for subdomain1. This can be done in your httpd.conf file. What kind of server do you have?

```
<VirtualHost subdomain1> 
ServerName subdomain1.example.com
ServerAdmin you@subdomain1.example.com
ServerAlias subdomain1.example.com     
DocumentRoot /path/to/subdomain1.example.com  
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have apache2 running?

Comment: If you do, I would recommend setting up virtual hosts in httpd.conf

Comment: <VirtualHost subdomain1>
    ServerAdmin you@subdomain1.example.com
    ServerAlias subdomain1.example.com
    DocumentRoot
    /path/to/subdomain1.example.com ServerName subdomain1.example.com
    </VirtualHost>

Comment: I already tried it, but I have another issues, and I'm still focus on it. sorry late for reply this. thanks